# Python - Count within 2d Array - OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I want to count within an 2d Array. E.g.:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list1.count(list2))
```

Result is: 2

Works like a charm. Now I got an 'example array' from OpenCV which is not working like the example before.

```
img = cv2.imread('./Unbenannt.png')
i = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
PixelArray = []


for a in range(i.shape[0]):
     PixelArray.append(i[a][0])
a = PixelArray[0]
print(PixelArray.count(a))
```

So at first I am reading an image, change from BGR to RGB (important for later steps). 
After this step I want to have an Array for the first 'row'. -> PixelArray
So the Result is an Array of Arrays with different color values. E.g. at the first position [255, 255, 255]. Now I want to count this color.  with:

```
print(PixelArray.count(a))
```

Now I get this Exception:

```
print(PixelArray.count(a))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So I don't know whats wrong. I already know that these Arrays within my PixelArray are a type 'dtype=uint8'.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you're trying to use the `list.count` method on a `numpy` array. You just need a small tweak inside the for loop to convert the arrays to lists:

```
for a in range(i.shape[0]): 

     PixelArray.append( list(i[a][0]) )

a = PixelArray[0]

print(PixelArray.count(a))
```

Alternatively you could use `np.unique`, and return a dictionary with the array as keys and counts as values. Then just search for your desired array in the dictionary (you need to convert `a` to a tuple to index the dictionary successfully):

```
for a in range(i.shape[0]):    
    PixelArray.append(i[a][0])

unq_rows, count = np.unique(PixelArray, axis=0, return_counts=True)

vec_counts_dictionary = {tuple(i):j for i,j in zip(unq_rows, count)}

a = tuple(PixelArray[0])

print(vec_counts_dictionary[a])
```